# Mixare Augmented Reality Engine: Replacing 2D planes with 3d objects?

Tags: android, frameworks, opengl-es, 3d, augmented-reality

Does anyone have a solution how to replace the 2D images with 3D objects?

Comment: We need some context here. What do you mean by 2D images? The marker?

Comment: Sorry I means the POIs. This is a location-based Augmented Reality [Framework](http://http://www.mixare.org/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a contribution to mixare (open source augmented reality browser: http://www.mixare.org) available here:
https://github.com/ferdinandtorggler/mixare/commit/0a8a7e070ef076239e0cb39606f3ac85faa324fe

It's used to display a grid on the horizon, so that's not quite what you want, but shows how to use openGL 3D objects inside mixare.

HTH